# Input dinamico con la directiva v-model en vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Tengo una consulta `v-for` el cual me trae los partidos de n jornada. Para cada partido tengo dos `input` donde el usuario marcara el resultado, necesito que el `v-model` de dichos `input` sean dinámicos.

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><abbr title="Position">Local</abbr></th>
              <th><abbr title="Played">Pronostico</abbr></th>
              <th><abbr title="Played">-</abbr></th>
              <th><abbr title="Won">Pronostico</abbr></th>
              <th><abbr title="Drawn">Visitante</abbr></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

            <tr v-for="match in matchdays">
              <th>
                <figure class="image is-32x32">
                  <img :src="'/img/shield/'+match.teamlocal.shield">
                </figure>
                {{ match.teamlocal.name }}
              </th>
              <th>
                <div class="field has-addons">
                  <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" v-model.number="local"
                           type="number" placeholder="0">
                  </p>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th> - </th>
              <th>
                <div class="field has-addons">
                  <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" v-model.number="visitante" 
                           type="number" placeholder="0">
                  </p>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>
                <figure class="image is-32x32">
                  <img :src="'/img/shield/'+match.teamvisitante.shield">
                </figure>
                {{ match.teamvisitante.name }}
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5" class="tdcolspan5">
                <div class="block">
                  <button class="button is-success" type="submit">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Save</span>
                  </button>
                  <!--<a class="button is-success">
                  <span class="icon is-small">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </span>
                <span>Save</span>
              </a>-->
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>

  {{ $data }}
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      matchdays: [],
      local: 0,
      visitante: 0
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.getMatches()
  },

  methods: {
    getMatches () {
      axios.get('/api/v1/matchday/'+this.$route.params.matchday )
      .then(response => {
        this.matchdays = response.data.matchdays.matches
      })
    },

    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
        console.log("ok")
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('fallo');
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        //alert('Correct them errors!');
      });
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gerardo, si pudieras separar el html, del javascript, seria mucho mejor para la lectura.

Comment: Hola Gerardo, podrías crear un __[mcve]__ con tu código. Utiliza el botón Snippet `<>`. O usa [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.com). Es importante saber como funciona lo que estás haciendo o los errores que tu código presenta.

Answer (score 2):

Como todo framework, Vue.js tiene cosillas que aún no han sido implementadas y debes de tener ingenio para solucionarlas. Para tu caso, se me ocurre poblar el objeto que almacena los `scores` inicializando `local` y `visitor` a null. Esto debes hacerlo en el hook `created`, antes que el componente sea montado.

```
created () {
  this.matches.forEach(match => {
    this.scores[match] = {
      local: null,
      visitor: null
    }
  })
}
```

Si a esto, le añades un formulario que envuelva los `inputs` podrías añadirles el atributo `required`, ya que, como se han inicializado los `scores` a null, Vue.js no asociará ningún valor a la etiqueta.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    matches: [{
        key: 'avcn2r',
        local: 'Barcelona',
        visitor: 'Sp Gijón'
      },
      {
        key: 'clm7rv',
        local: 'Real Madrid',
        visitor: 'Las Palmas'
      },
      {
        key: '2kd034',
        local: 'Liverpool',
        visitor: 'Arsenal'
      },
      {
        key: 'pmkd29',
        local: 'Juventus',
        visitor: 'Sampdoria'
      }
    ],
    scores: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    showScores() {
      console.log(this.scores)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.matches.forEach(match => {
      this.scores[match.key] = {
        local: match.local,
        visitor: match.visitor,
        scores: [null, null]
      }
    })
  }
})

app.$mount('#app')
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #009BFF;
  border: 1px solid #009BFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

table thead {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
}

table th,
table td {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table tr:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

table td:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

table input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="showScores">Show scores</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Local</th>
        <th>Visitante</th>
        <th>Resultado</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="match in matches">
        <td>{{ match.local }}</td>
        <td>{{ match.visitor }}</td>
        <td>
          <input v-model.number="scores[match.key].scores[0]" type="number" min="0" />
          <input v-model.number="scores[match.key].scores[1]" type="number" min="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Nota que aquí he usado claves random, pero puedes usar como clave la concatenación de ambos equipos por ejemplo, ya es cuestión de tu preferencia o de la API que uses.